# Fetching data from second database connection inside class extending Doctrine\DBAL\Connection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I use a custom wrapper_class for one of my dbal connections named ClientDatabaseConnector

ClientDatabaseConnector.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Doctrine\Common\EventManager;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver;

class ClientDatabaseConnector extends Connection
{

  public function __construct(array $params, Driver $driver, ?Configuration $config = null, ?EventManager $eventManager = null)
  {

    parent::__construct($params, $driver, $config, $eventManager);
  }

}
```

doctrine.yaml

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: master
        connections:
            master:
                url: '%env(resolve:MASTER_DATABASE_URL)%'
            client:
                wrapper_class: App\Service\ClientDatabaseConnector
                url: '~'
```

I'm trying to access the first database inside the ClientDatabaseConnector class.

I've tried this in services.yaml

```yaml
    app.services.clientDatabaseConnector:
        class: App\Service\ClientDatabaseConnector
        arguments: 
           $doctrine: '@doctrine'
```

But it doesn't work. How can I access my first db connection so I can query it to get database information?

Answer (score 1):

Symfony already creates the connection services for you using a default naming format.  If you use 'bin/console debug:container Connection' you will see that you have a service named 'doctrine.dbal.client_connection' which you can inject into other services.  No need to make any entry in services.yaml for the service to be available.

However, it appears that you are using a reasonably up to date version of Symfony which means you can also autowire the connection by adding an alias for the connection class:

```
# config/services.yaml
services: 

    # create the alias
    App\Service\ClientDatabaseConnector: '@doctrine.dbal.client_connection'

# and inject it SomeService.php
class SomeService {
    public function __construct(App\Service\ClientDatabaseConnector $conn)
```

Note: In my original answer I specifically excluded the ClientDatabaseConnector class so as to avoid attempts to automatically wire it up.  I was using code from a Symfony 4 project.  Not sure why I excluded it back then.  It is not necessary.  Just creating the alias is all that is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I have two database connections, master and client. 

What I'm trying to do is access the master connection inside ClientDatabaseConnector.
I want to query master connection to fetch database parameters and dynamically setup client connection. 

When I tried injecting doctrine in constructor I got an error saying 4 parameters given, expecting 5 or something like that.

Comment: I was afraid you were asking something like that.  Doctrine of course knows nothing about the Symfony container.  DBAL Connections are independent objects.  You really can't create one without passing all the necessary parameters.  I think you probably need to drop down to the doctrine level and make some sort of connection factory and then figure out how to make your connections available to Symfony.  Or perhaps use a different design.  Good luck.